# How to add phtml page on shipping page in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml

i am adding a phtml page on shipping page but its also adding on payment page

checkout_index_index.xml.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-left">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="SY\Avatar\Block\Customer\Account\Avatar" name="customer_account_avatar" as="customer.account.avatar" before="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="customer/account/Otp.phtml" />
            <action method="setPosition">
                  <argument name="position" xsi:type="string">checkout-content-top</argument>
              </action>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

but its on also payment page. what should i do ? anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to add the action **inside the block** like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="SY\Avatar\Block\Customer\Account\Avatar" name="customer_account_avatar" as="customer.account.avatar" before="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="customer/account/Otp.phtml">
              <action method="setPosition">
                  <argument name="position" xsi:type="string">checkout-content-top</argument>
              </action>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

To add a simplest phtml file you could use this xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="block.container" htmlTag="div" htmlId="test.id.container" htmlClass="block-home-container" before="">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block.banner" as="block.custom.cms" template="Magento_Theme::block.phtml" after="-" />
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

> The **action** is instanciate inside the **referenceBlock** and **block** not on **referenceContainer**.

Comment: its not working for me .. i fallowed your instruction

Comment: still otp.phtml is showing on shipping and payment page

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari try to remove the 2columns-left like I did now on my answer.

Comment: its still not working ...

Comment: Try to change the class of your block, to compare with your custom class is right. Use this class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: still is not working

Comment: Check the name of your XML file.

Comment: checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: If the generic class above doesn't work, maybe this file doesn't exist or the theme edited is wrong, or the folder structure. Try apply the generic class and into the default.xml to check the file and folders.